# Laravel Passport wont create Laravel_token and then error 401 Unauthenticated will shows when consuming own API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

After couple of days investigation on this issue plus reading all questions/solutions about it I decided to share this issue with you guys.
**My current main issue is:**
laravel_token is not creating using Laravel passport consuming own API.
However it is creating when user logged in.

Running on:

- vagrant local host, window 10
- Laravel 5.8
- Passport:7.3
- Using multi guards for API
- Using Axios to use API
- Using Vue to submit the form

**Brief description about project**
*Have a place order system API to place orders by either Admin or site visitors.
It is going to use API for both.* 
So I have 2 guards : Admins, Users 
**Here is what I have done:**

- Installed passport and have done all steps mentioned on this document:
  https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport
- Done this part to use my own API : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

here is my config\auth.php:

```php
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver'    => 'session',
            'provider'  =>  'admins'
        ],

        'admin-api' =>  [
            'driver'    =>  'passport',
            'provider'  =>  'admins'
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

- Added HasApiTokens, in both User and Admin models
- Added guard name in Admin models

*Admin Model*

```php
    protected $guard = 'admin';
    protected $guard_name = 'admin';
```

*app\Http\Kernel.php*

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
....
\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
],
'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
```

*app\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php*

```php
protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Passport::routes();

        Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(15));

        Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(30));
    }
```

*Api route*

```php
...
//admin CRUD orders
Route::middleware('auth:admin-api')->group(function(){
        Route::apiResource('orders', 'Api\OrderController');
    }); //works fine because admin user needs to login
//when consuming own API, wont work!!

//I was thinking passport needs a GET request to 
//create Cookie, it is still not working if I remove it
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function(){
        Route::get('orders/refresh-token', 'Api\OrderController@refreshToken')->name('orders.refresh-token'); 
//when form is submitted
        Route::put('orders/complete-store-order', 'Api\OrderController@completetStore')->name('orders.complete-store-order');
    }); 
...
```

Added headers when compile js file:

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
 window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
     'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
     'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token.content,
 };
```

**My current issue is :**
`laravel_token` cookie is not generated when consuming own API, however it is generating when `Admin user` logged in!
**What I have found in passport files :**

1) **When consuming own API** in file `vendor\laravel\passport\src\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken.php` line 48 under handle function: $gurad is null

2) **When consuming own API** in same file line : 83 under function : `requestShouldReceiveFreshToken`: `$request->user($this->guard)` **is always** `null` because there is no user, but when using Passport when user logged this is NOT empty and it will generate Cookie and works perfectly.
 How user is getting populated when consuming own API??

Here are some screen shots on my requests headers,... that can help:

1) request header contains when Admin user logged in:
[image]
2)Sending headers when consuming own API
[image]

Answer (score 0):

May you have to insert the user token in the header to perform auth API calls.

`Authorization: Bearer {{$token}}`

I used this easy tutorial: https://medium.com/techcompose/create-rest-api-in-laravel-with-authentication-using-passport-133a1678a876